# (Umschreibender) Terminus für eine Person, die immer ihre Termine einhält

Tags: single-word-request

Gibt es im Deutschen einen (umschreibenden) Terminus für eine Person, die immer ihre Termine einhält und Sachen immer fristgerecht erledigt?

Ziemlich oberflächlich wäre sicherlich das Nomen "Perfektionist". Hier stört mich leider, dass das Nomen für viel zu viele verschiedene Bedeutungen verwendet wird und daher nicht präzise genug ist. Ich hoffe, dass die Community mir hierbei helfen kann :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Will man kennzeichnen, das jemand die personifizierte Termineinhaltungsmaschine ist, dann sagt man

> Er ist die Pünktlichkeit in Person

oder

> Er ist die Pünktlichkeit selbst

Comment: Super Gedankenanstoß! Danke!

Comment: *Termineinhaltungsmaschine* war eigentlich auch ein guter Vorschlag.

Answer (score 4):

### [pünktlich](https://www.dwds.de/wb/p%C3%BCnktlich)

Mit dem positiv besetzten [pünktlich](https://www.dwds.de/wb/p%C3%BCnktlich) bringt man vor allem zum Ausdruck, dass jemand Termine fristgerecht einhält. Früher war auch Zuverlässigkeit in weiter gefassten Bereichen Teil der Pünktlichkeit, diese Konnotation geht jedoch allmählich verloren.

> Kurt ist ein ausgeprochen **pünktlicher** Mensch.

Etwas weiter gefasste Synonyme, die hier ganz gut passen wären noch: *verlässlich, akkurat, gewissenhaft*.

Comment: Herzlichen Dank für die Antwort. Aus Neugier will ich noch nachfragen, ob es hierzu ein Nomen gibt, das den "pünktlichen Menschen" ersetzt?

Dann wären wir an dieser Stelle wieder bei der eigentlichen Ausgangslage dieser Frage nach dem Terminus angelangt, nach dem ich suche, aber von dem ich nicht weiß, ob dieser auch existiert :) VG, Steff

Comment: @SteffPoint: mir ist keines eingefallen, aber vielleicht hat jemand eine Idee.

Comment: Pünktlich selbst ist nicht positiv besetzt. Es kommt immer auf den Kontext an - diese sind freilich meist so, dass man Pünktlichkeit bevorzugt, aber wenn man pünktlich die Kündigung bekommen hat oder das Todesurteil pünktlich vollstreckt wird kann es genausogut negativ sein.

Comment: @userunknown: ähm - der Kontext ist doch bekannt!

Comment: Tja. Der Kontext sorgt für die positive Wertung, nicht das Wort - ein immer und immer wieder zu beobachtender Fehler. Ist das jetzt gängige Praxis im Deutschunterricht, dass man Begriffe in positive und negative sortiert - so als maximale Simplifikation? Eine äußerst infantile, antiintellektuelle Praxis, die man nicht unterstützen sollte. Welches Wort soll ich denn statt "pünktlich" benutzen um eine negative Wertung zu transportieren?

Comment: @userunknown: ganz richtig! Genau so ist es.

Answer (score 2):

Termine immer einhalten und Sachen immer fristgerecht erledigen könnte man zusammen mit

> [termingenau](https://www.dwds.de/wb/termingenau)

bezeichnen.

> Als Pedant ist Herr Nowak immer auch termingenau.

Ein gelistetes Nomen für eine stets pünktliche und fristgerecht arbeitende Person habe ich nicht gefunden, da bleibt nur eine Eigenbildung:

> Terminkünstler

Comment: Danke schön für den Vorschlag :)

Comment: Eigentlich beschreibt _termingenau_ die zu einem bestimmten Termin zu erledigende Sache näher, und nicht die Person, die diese Sache erledigt. Also "_die termingenaue Lieferung_" oder "_termingenaue Abbuchung_," nicht aber "_der termingenaue Lieferer_" oder "_der termingenaue Gläubiger_".

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Da mir das klar war, habe ich _»könnte«_ geschrieben. Aber im Deutschen sind wir ja flexibel, wobei bei _»übergenau«_ und _»hypergenau«_ der Personenbezug bereits zu überwiegen scheint.

Answer (score 1):

Hier ist noch eine gebräuchliche und hübsche Wendung, die sich auch auf Personen anwenden lässt:

> Pünktlich wie die Eieruhr

Beim längeren Nachdenken über diesen Ausdruck (auch nach Kommentator Tofros Einwand zur technischen Pünktlichkeit von Eieruhren) drängt sich  mir der Eindruck auf, dass diese Redewendung möglicherweise eine Verballhornung ist des seinerzeit wohl überwiegend gültigen

> Pünktlich wie die Eisenbahn

---

Ergänzendes / Beiläufiges

Ich grüble, ob sich nicht noch etwas finden ließe von der Art des bei unseren amerikanischen Freunden so beliebten Epithetons *grammar nazi*... Aber *Du bist ein Termin-Nazi* funktioniert im Deutschen (noch?) nicht so recht. Für unsere a. F. ist ein *nazi* im Alltagssprachgebrauch oft bloß jemand, der sich übermäßig stark an Regeln und Vorgaben hält (beziehungsweise andere zu deren Einhaltung drängt), während im Deutschen eine solche laxe Wortverwendung befremdlich wäre.

Kommentator Mtwde (siehe unten) hat hierzu noch den etablierten und angemessenen deutschen Ausdruck gefunden:

> Pünktlichkeitsfanatiker

Comment: Rein logisch betrachtet, ist eine Eieruhr nicht *pünktlich* - Sie misst nur relative Zeiten, keine absoluten.

Comment: @tofro  Technisch gesehen magst du recht haben. Hier wurde aber nicht nach den Besonderheiten von Uhrkonstruktionen gefragt sondern nach Ausdrücken im Deutschen für Leute, die besonders pünktlich sind, und *pünktlich wie die Eieruhr* ist eine verbreitete Metapher, wenigstens in dem sprachlichen Umfeld, dem ich ausgesetzt bin.

Comment: Tatsächlich? Du scheinst dich unter unlogischen Leuten zu bewegen- ich habe diesen Ausdruck noch nie gehört

Comment: Sollte man tatsächlich einen Terminus, der in diese Richtung geht, suchen würde sich wohl eher der "Termin-Blockwart" anbieten. Alternativ und etabliert ist allerdings schon der "Pünktlichkeitsfanatiker"

Comment: Danke schön für das Gedankengut. Ich habe auch schon von dieser Wendung gehört.

Comment: @tofro  Du findest, dein Umfeld verhält sich in Alltag und Sprachgebahren logisch? Wohnst du in einer Roboterkolonie? - Scherz beiseite: Der überwiegende Teil der Leute, die Sprache verwenden, verwendet Sie, finde ich, ohne  nachzudenken und sagt oft Sachen, die weit unangemessener und logikwidriger sind als *pünktlich* bei der Eieruhr. Zum Beispiel sagen sie: *Ich entschuldige mich* und übersehen, dass nur das Gegenüber selbst in der Lage wäre, etwas zu entschuldigen, nicht aber sie sich selbst.

Comment: Ziemlich geläufig für ein adverbiales 'superpünktlich' ist in meiner Gegend (Ruhrgebiet) auch die Wendung 'pünktlich wie die Maurer'. Oft als Kommentar, wenn jemand pünktlich kommt: _Leute, ich bin sprachlos: Pünktlich wie die Maurer! Was ist auf denn auf einmal los mit euch, sonst habt ihr doch die Ruhe weg!_